# Incremental Backups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to do Incremental backups in Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409046/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-incremental-backups-in-mysql)

Can anyone help me to take incremental backup in MySQL?

Answer (score 8):

Check the [MySQL ::   MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 6.2 Database Backup Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) page and read the "Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log" section. We can't put it clearer than that :)

In case the site goes down:

> #### Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log
>
> MySQL supports incremental backups: You must start the server with
> the --log-bin option to enable binary logging; see Section 5.2.4, “The
> Binary Log”. The binary log files provide you with the information you
> need to replicate changes to the database that are made subsequent to
> the point at which you performed a backup. At the moment you want to
> make an incremental backup (containing all changes that happened since
> the last full or incremental backup), you should rotate the binary log
> by using FLUSH LOGS. This done, you need to copy to the backup
> location all binary logs which range from the one of the moment of the
> last full or incremental backup to the last but one. These binary logs
> are the incremental backup; at restore time, you apply them as
> explained in Section 7.5, “Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using
> the Binary Log”. The next time you do a full backup, you should also
> rotate the binary log using FLUSH LOGS, mysqldump --flush-logs, or
> mysqlhotcopy --flushlog. See Section 4.5.4, “mysqldump — A Database
> Backup Program”, and Section 4.6.9, “mysqlhotcopy — A Database Backup
> Program”.

Another option is to use MySQLDump, and diff the new dumpfile version an old(er) one, then only store the diff. See the implementation example at [MySQLDump comment section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

For posterity, the script is included below.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Incremental backup script using rdiff
# Author: Driantsov Alexander
# Requirements:
# * rdiff-backup - http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/
# * rsync
# * ssh ;)
####

BACKUP_ADMIN_EMAIL="yourmail@yourserver.com"
BACKUP_MAIL_SUBJECT="`hostname`: SQL Backup Synchronization Result"
BACKUP_LOG="/var/log/backup-sql"

BACKUP_PRIO="20" # Priority for the MySQL dump and rdiff-backup Min: 20 Max: -20
BACKUP_TMP_DIR="/var/backup/mysql_tmp" # New dumps will be stored here
BACKUP_DIFF_DIR="/var/backup/hosting/mysql" # Diffs of dumps will be stored there
SYNC_SRV="BAC.KUP.SER.VER" # Remote server for backup storage
SYNC_USER="backup_user" # User at remote storage
SYNC_SPEED="200" # Limit Synchronization Bandwidth to this number of KB/s
SYNC_DIR="/backup/hosting/mysql" #Directory on Remote server to synchronize backups in
MYSQL_USER="admin" # MySQL user
MYSQL_PASSWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` # Password for MySQL. You may obtain password from /etc/psa/.psa.shadow if you are using Plesk on your server.

#Implementaition
RSCONSTR="$SYNC_USER@$SYNC_SRV"
# Dump
echo "Backup Started at `date`" > $BACKUP_LOG
load_average=`uptime|awk {print $10" "$11" "$12}`
echo "Load overage at start: $load_average" >> $BACKUP_LOG
echo "\nBackingUP MySQL:" >> $BACKUP_LOG
for i in `mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWD -Bse "show databases"`; do echo "Backing up database $i..." >> $BACKUP_LOG ; nice -n $BACKUP_PRIO mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --skip-extended-insert -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWD $i > $BACKUP_TMP_DIR/$i.dump; done

echo "MySQL dump completed at `date`" >> $BACKUP_LOG
load_average=`uptime|awk {print $10" "$11" "$12}`
echo "\nLoad overage after MySQL dumps: $load_average\n" >> $BACKUP_LOG
# Diff
echo "Looking for difference in database" >> $BACKUP_LOG
nice -n $BACKUP_PRIO rdiff-backup $BACKUP_TMP_DIR $BACKUP_DIFF_DIR/$HOSTNAME 2>&1 >> $BACKUP_LOG
echo "Done" >> $BACKUP_LOG

echo "Rdiff-backup completed at `date`" >> $BACKUP_LOG
load_average=`uptime|awk {print $10" "$11" "$12}`
echo "\nLoad overage after rdiff-backup: $load_average\n" >> $BACKUP_LOG

# Synchronize

sql_result=`rsync -avz --bwlimit $SYNC_SPEED $BACKUP_DIFF_DIR $RSCONSTR:$SYNC_DIR|tail -n 2`
free_space_info=`ssh $RSCONSTR df -h --sync -t ext3`

echo -en " MySQL backup synchronization:\n $sql_result \nSynchronization completed at `date` \n\nInformation on free space on remote backup server: \n $free_space_info \n\n Backup Log: \n\n`cat $BACKUP_LOG`"| mail -s "$BACKUP_MAIL_SUBJECT" $BACKUP_ADMIN_EMAIL
```

Comment: If you need more details on my blog I described exactly this approach to perform a [MySQL incremental backup with mysqldump and rdiff-backup](https://www.guguweb.com/2020/01/30/mysql-incremental-backup-with-mysqldump-and-rdiff-backup/).