# How to do a incremental backup in Mysql

Tags: mysql, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to do Incremental backups in Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409046/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-incremental-backups-in-mysql)

Is there a way to do <strike>differential</strike> incremental backup in MySQL ? I dont know if there is a PHP script or shell script able to do this.

I believe each tables states must be saved and their differences must be exported in the backup. Any way to accomplish this?

I know there are other types of backup but I like the way smallers backup are generated at time in <strike>differential</strike> incremental backups.

**Edit:**

I forgot to specify that my DB engine is `InnoDB`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, is called **incremental backup** instead of differential backup
(correct me if I making wrong assumption)

use binary log (replication sql log)

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

in nutshell, binary log contains list of write sql (insert,delete,update,alter table...) and execute these statement sequentially will provide a incremental update (which is what replication does)

Comment: To be honest I dont know which solutions (differential or incremental) is better since I've never had to implement a backup solutions before. But I believe the incremental backup could do the job. I will take a look at your links. Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: A `differential backup` backs up only the files that changed since the last full back up. `Incremental backups` back up files that changed after differential backups but they can also be made from files changed after full backups too. Incremental backups are sometimes called "differential incremental backups."