# MySQL Incremental backup

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql server, try to take backup of database  on daily bases only changes needed for backup and please provide how to setup incremental backup on mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to do incremental backups in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409046/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-incremental-backups-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two tools available in the market which supports the incremental backup 1- Percona Xtra Backup; it is free and easy to use 2 - mysqlbackup, this comes with enterprise MySQL license only.

Answer (score 1):

While Percona Xtrabackup can do the job even for large databases, IMHO it is a bit complex to install and setup.

For small to medium databases a simpler approach uses a combination of mysqldump and rdiff-backup to obtain an incremental mysql backup. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --skip-extended-insert --routines -umyuser -pmysecret dbname > /path/to/dumps/dir/dbname.dump;
rdiff-backup /path/to/dumps/dir/ /path/to/backup/dir/
```

On my blog you can read more details on how to perform [MySQL incremental backup with mysqldump and rdiff-backup](https://www.guguweb.com/2020/01/30/mysql-incremental-backup-with-mysqldump-and-rdiff-backup/).